# Get parent attribute value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the data-value 'Tomatoe' from this code when the user is typing in the input:

```js
$('input[name=txt]').on('input', function() {
  var module = $(this).closest('[data-value]').val();
  alert(module);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value="Tomatoe">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm missing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Divs don't have a value property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<div>` has no `value`, so `.val()` won't produce anything meaningful.  You want the jQuery `.data()` function:

```js
$('input[name=txt]').on('input', function() {
  var module = $(this).closest('[data-value]').data('value');
  alert(module);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-value="Tomatoe">
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txt" required>
  </div>
</div>
```